# JS Flow: What is the most clean and concise way to define an enum that is also treated like a type

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Coming from a strongly typed language I recently took my first steps with  React Native. I am using Flow as a static type checker. However I did not yet find a clean and concise way to define an enum type that is treated like a type and triggers the 'compiler' to suggest me the possible values in VS Code.

Currently I try to accomplish this in the following way

```
export const CompletionStates = {
    CompletionStateUnbegun: 'unbegun',
    CompletionStateRunning: 'running',
    CompletionStateLost: 'lost',
    CompletionStateWon: 'won',
    CompletionStateCancelled: 'cancelled',
}

export type CompletionState = 
    | CompletionStates.CompletionStateUnbegun 
    | CompletionStates.CompletionStateRunning  
    | CompletionStates.CompletionStateLost 
    | CompletionStates.CompletionStateWon 
    | CompletionStates.CompletionStateCancelled;
```

Does anyone know a more concise and clean approach to define an enumeration using Flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $Values:

```
type CompletionStates = {
    CompletionStateUnbegun: 'unbegun',
    CompletionStateRunning: 'running',
    CompletionStateLost: 'lost',
    CompletionStateWon: 'won',
    CompletionStateCancelled: 'cancelled',
};

export type CompletionState = $Values<CompletionStates>;
```

Comment: Thanks, using $Values instead of listing the possible CompletionState seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I define an enum in the following way

you defined a `const` and a `type` here. You can also define directly an `enum`:

```
export enum Animals {
  DOG = "Dog", 
  CAT = "cat"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, of course you are right. I have slightly edited my question.